# how to convert string input value to numerical value in flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a form that predicts a player performance based on the name. However, request.form['player_name'] returns a string. how can i convert the string into numerical value?

I tried this below code but it always give me the result of the player_name 0.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()

@flask_app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    player_name = le.fit_transform([request.form['player_name']])
    return render_template("index.html", prediction_text="The Player name is {}".format(player_name))
```

Comment: [`fit_transform` takes an array](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.fit_transform) (array-like technically)

Comment: Flask isn't the issue. What information did you find when you searched how to parse a string to number in Python?

Comment: It also isn't very clear what you're trying to do, you say you want to transform a string into a numerical value, I assue with `fit_transform`, but then `player_name`, the result of that transformation you want to use it as a string (or it looks like that). What do you expect to output? `The Player name is` what? `The Player name is 69`? `The Player name is 198749202`? `The Player name is Daviid`?

Comment: i want the output of 'the player name is 69' like that. i want the numerical value of that player name. because in my prediction model players name is in numerical value

Comment: If you want to convert the `player_name` value of the form, you can use the [`get`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get) command of the `MultiDict` and assign the `type` attribute. You can also specify a default value.